# How to create 3 arrays from 1 multidimensional array with 2 arrays inside

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 1 multidimensional array with 2 diff arrays and 3 values each. I want to create 3 diff arrays merging the keys of the 2 arrays

```
$address = ['head office','branch 1','branch 2'];
$address_tag = ['No 2 Str', '#12 first floor','Grand floor l Plaze'];
$arr = $keparr = []; 
$i = 0;
foreach ([$address_tag,$address] as $k => $v) {
    $vCount = count($v);
    foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
        $keparr[$i][] = $v2;
    }
    $arr[] = $keparr;
    $i++;
    if($i === $vCount) $i = 0;
}
$arr = [
    ['head office','No 2 Str'],
    ['branch 1','#12 first floor'],
    ['branch 2','Grand floor l plaza']
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array=array_map(null,$array1,$array2,$array3);
```

And can More array

```
$arr=array_map(null,$adress,$adress_tag);
print_r($arr);
```